# Makefile error when building on Cygwin

Tags: makefile, build, cygwin

I am installing some NASA's software (HEASoft) from the source code on Cygwin (32-bit) running on Windows 10. Configure ran successfully, but make gives the following errors:

```
Makefile:26: /home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/heacore/BUILD_DIR/Makefile-std: No such file or directory
gmake[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/heacore/BUILD_DIR/Makefile-std'.  Stop.
gmake[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/cygwin/home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/heacore/BUILD_DIR'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:74: heacore] Error 2 
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/BUILD_DIR'
make: *** [Makefile:10: all] Error 2
```

My problem is that the file `/home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/heacore/BUILD_DIR/Makefile-std` is not found; however, it actually exists and is located in the correct directory. EDIT: here it can be seen that this file exists:

```
$ ls /home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/heacore/BUILD_DIR
config.guess   config.sub    hd_config_info  headas-init.csh  headas-setup.in  hmakerc     lhea-fixperl  Makefile-CCfits
config.log     configure     hd_install.c    headas-init.sh   hmake            hmakerc.in  Makefile      Makefile-std
config.status  configure.in  hd_scanenv      headas-setup     hmake_hd         install-sh  Makefile.in
```

Any clue why this might be happening and how can be solved?

Comment: how do you know it exists? can you try `ls /home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/heacore/BUILD_DIR` and post the results in your question (by [edit]ing it, not in the comments)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error when building NASA's HEASARC software HEASoft on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45284620/error-when-building-nasas-heasarc-software-heasoft-on-cygwin)

Comment: please don't post the exact same question twice!

Comment: So what else can I do if I don't get any answer?

Comment: Ask a clearer question. For one thing, you are not compiling both C and C++. So remove the irrelevent tag please.

Comment: did you `cd` to that directory and run `make`? As mentioned before, did you try `ls /home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/heacore/BUILD_DIR`?

Comment: I didn't cd to that directory to run make because make is supposed to be run in /home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/BUILD_DIR, where configure is run before make. Also, I tried ls /home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/heacore/BUILD_DIR to check if the file is there, and it is (I edited the question to show this).

Comment: @Mario: We are voluntairs, not getting any money. There is no guarantee you get an answer at all. Less, if you don't follow  [ask].

Comment: @Mario: I do not see a `ls /home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/heacore/BUILD_DIR` in your question, I only see a ls in that directory, that's not the same. Please follow the tipps from @Olaf et all, thanks.

Comment: @Olaf I know and I understand your point. This is the first time I ask because this is the first time I haven't found a solution searching and reading other questions and answers. It's just frustrating getting only negative votes to a question but no comments, making less likely for that question to be answered. That's why I repeated my question (Jean-François Fabre, Florian Weimer), which I think is the only thing in the how-to-ask policies that I didn't follow. I didn't mean to bother anyone, so sorry if I did.

Comment: @Tom Kuschel That's right, sorry. Here is what you asked:

    $ ls /home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/heacore/BUILD_DIR
config.guess   config.sub    hd_config_info  headas-init.csh  headas-setup.in  hmakerc     lhea-fixperl  Makefile-CCfits
config.log     configure     hd_install.c    headas-init.sh   hmake            hmakerc.in  Makefile      Makefile-std
config.status  configure.in  hd_scanenv      headas-setup     hmake_hd         install-sh  Makefile.in

Comment: "which I think is the only thing in the how-to-ask policies that I didn't follow" - So both of your questions are downvoted just because it is cool … yeah …

Comment: I didn't say that, @Olaf.

Comment: Can you see into line 26 of Makefile - maybe there is a inclusion or a file which is not found.

Comment: This is line 26 of Makefile: 

    `${HD_TOP_EXEC_PFX}/headas-init.csh ${HD_LN_S};`

The headas-init.csh file exists too: 

    `$ ls /home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/heacore/BUILD_DIR *headas-init*
headas-init.csh  headas-init.sh`

Answer (score -1):

When Cygwin shell is opened `cd /cygdrive/c/home/Mario` and run make on your project from that directory. I remember I had similar issue when the current directory was `/home/foo`. I got it solved just changing the directory to `/cygdrive/c/home/foo` which is definitely is the same directory, but somehow Cygwin's Make likes it better

Comment: In my case, `/cygdrive/c/home/Mario` doesn't exist, the equivalent path to this directory is `C:/cygwin/home/Mario` instead. So I `cd C:/cygwin/home/Mario` and run `make` from there like this: `$ make -C C:/cygwin/home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/BUILD_DIR` but I get the same error that I got running `make` from `/home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/BUILD_DIR`. Did I understand right what you mean?

Comment: `/cygdrive/c/` should exist in any case. Can you post result of running `ls /cygdrive/c/` command?

Comment: `$ ls /cygdrive/c/
'$GetCurrent'           logs                RecoveryRecycle.Bin'             MinGW               Strawberry  bootmgr                OEM                 swapfile.sys
 BOOTNXT                OneDriveTemp       'System Volume Information'
 Config.Msi                pagefile.sys           texlive
 cygwin                 PerfLogs               Users
'Documents and Settings'  'Program Files'         Windows
 emacs-25.2-x86_64        'Program Files (x86)'   Windows10Upgrade
 hiberfil.sys              ProgramData            xls.html
 Intel                     Python27`

Comment: So it should be `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/Mario`

Comment: So, I `$ cd /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/Mario/` and then `$ make -C /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/Mario/heasoft-6.21/BUILD_DIR/` as @Alexey suggest, but still get the exact same error.